# Prince of Persia: Zurvan and Dark Prince

Tags: prince-of-persia

In Prince of Persia: The Two Thrones, the Vizier stabs himself with the Dagger of Time and turns into a sand monster known as [the Zurvan](http://princeofpersia.wikia.com/wiki/Zurvan_(Sand_Creature)).

If the titular Prince had impaled himself with the dagger, would he just become the Dark Prince or would he be a more twisted form of the Vizier's sand monster?